# Binding a Resource to a View Model

Tags: wpf, data-binding, resources

How do you bind data from the view model into an object in the resources of the user control?  Here is a very abstract example:

```
<UserControl ... 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.Local.Namespace"
             Name="userControl">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:GroupingProvider x:Key="groupingProvider" GroupValue="{Binding ???}" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <local:GroupingConsumer Name="groupingConsumer1" Provider={StaticResource groupingProvider"} />
        <local:GroupingConsumer Name="groupingConsumer2" Provider={StaticResource groupingProvider"} />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How do I bind `GroupValue` to a property in the view model behind this view.  I've tried the following:

```
<local:GroupingProvider x:Key="groupingProvider" GroupValue="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=DataContext.Property}"/>
```

But this doesn't work.

**Edit:**

`GroupProvider` extends `DependencyObject` and `GroupValue` is the name of a `DependencyProperty`.  I'm getting the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Property; DataItem=null; target element is 'GroupingProvider' (HashCode=47478197); target property is 'GroupValue' (type 'TimeSpan')
```

This seems to suggest that it cannot find `userControl`.

**More Edit:**

Nobody has an answer to my question?  Is there not a way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? If so would you mind to share?

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit late, but i had the same problem. Ricks answer is right, you need to inherit from `Freezable`.

The following Code gave me the same error as you got

Not working resource:

```
public class PrintBarcodesDocumentHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public IEnumerable<BarcodeResult> Barcodes
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<BarcodeResult>)GetValue(BarcodesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BarcodesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BarcodesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Barcodes", typeof(IEnumerable<BarcodeResult>), typeof(PrintBarcodesDocumentHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null, HandleBarcodesChanged));

    private static void HandleBarcodesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Barcodes:PrintBarcodesDocumentHelper x:Key="docHelper" Barcodes="{Binding BarcodeResults}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

My viewmodel is bound to the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`.

Error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=BarcodeResults; DataItem=null; target element is 'PrintBarcodesDocumentHelper' (HashCode=55335902); target property is 'Barcodes' (type 'IEnumerable`1')
```

Working resource class:

```
public class PrintBarcodesDocumentHelper : Freezable
{
    // Same properties

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new PrintBarcodesDocumentHelper();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately i dont know why it have to be a `Freezable`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable binding, `GroupingProvider` needs to be derived from `Freezable` or `FrameworkElement` or `FrameworkContentElement` and `GroupValue` needs to be a `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: `GroupProvider` extends `DependencyObject` and `GroupValue` is the name of a `DependencyProperty`.  I believe binding only requires extention of `DependencyObject`; I tried changing to `FrameworkElement` but it didn't work. Read my edits above.  The problem seems to be in referencing the data context from within resources.

Comment: FrameworkElement did not work for me. Just Freezable.